# Effectively test a database backend

Tags: database, unit-testing, testing

I have a database-backed application which, sadly, has very few tests of its database.  I'm trying to get up to speed on effectively testing the database.

So far, I've learned:

- test the ability of the application to put/fetch data to the database
- use mock DB's to test object/relation-mapping code

**I'm still struggling to implement the first point.**  It seems that the only way to test that is to insert data into the real tables.  But of course the user won't want to see my test data.  Here's what I'm currently doing in pseudo-code:

```
begin a transaction
insert a few rows
check that no error has occurred
'select' the rows back out
check that no error has occurred, check that data out matches data in
tell the test framework that it's successful
abort the transaction
```

Is this a best practice, or some kind of horrible anti-pattern?  Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user definitely shouldn't see your test data, because testing in production is really bad practice! You should try to create a test environment and do your testing there.

One solution I've found to work is to create a separate database instance, populate it with some known data, and use that for your integration testing. Be sure to clean up your database after each test case, as test cases should be independent.

Using transactions in the test database is not such a bad practice, since you can confirm things and then rollback the transaction, but I would be concerned that you're going to call code that will commit to the database, thereby changing the parameters for following tests. Of course, if your DB supports nested transactions, this isn't a big deal, but ISTM that not all DBs do that.

Comment: +1 as I think you've raised some good points, but I'm not sure I understand why `testing in production is really bad practice`.  I would've thought that it was a good practice -- because one point of the database tests is to verify that the application on the user's computer can talk to the database on the user's computer, i.e. that everything is installed properly.  OTOH, that statement makes sense to me in the context of checking whether the database schema is what the application expects it to be.

Comment: Generally a bad idea for a reason you brought up! Let's say something going wrong in testing, you don't want to hose your production environment. You also don't want to pollute your production database with test data, which make it hard to do metrics on your production data and can occasionally cause customer's to wonder what's going on. Also, with a test database you can control the contents - this allows you to make real calls to say, get the number of users and test against it, while that data is everchanging in production.

Comment: Ran out of comment space. It's in industry best practice to have at least three environments: production (duh), testing (so you can check changes before they go into production with known data), and development (because developers frequently muck stuff up while figuring things out, and you don't want have developed features interfering with testing or worse, production).

Comment: This is really helping a lot -- just still unclear on what testing is done on the user's system to make sure that the application can reach the database, and that the database has not been damaged or altered.

Comment: If you do your testing well in your QA/test/lab/whatever environment, you shouldn't need to do much if any testing on the user's machine. (Perhaps a validation script at the beginning to check that the user has access to the database or something at most). Your system should be machine agnostic, so testing in a test environment is equivalent to testing in a production environment, but without the risk of polluting the production system or finding a critical bug by means of crashing the system.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, we should have 3 different environments like dev, qa and production environments. You should not play with production data why because some times the data replicated to some distributed databases and if you are not aware the replication it will create unnecessary problems.

~Temruzinn